# Calculating Conditional Distributions using Copula in R

Tags: r, probability, copula

I have three random variables `X`, `Z`, and `Y`, and I know their distribution functions `F(X)`, `F(Z)`, and `F(Y)`. However, the dependence structure among them is not known. I want to calculate the conditional distributions `F(Y|X)` and `F(X|Y)` given `X`, `Z`, and `Y`.

I'm using the `copula` and `gamlss.dist` packages in R to generate a Gumbel copula with theta=2 and create a multivariate distribution (`mvdc`). The code snippet below generates a specific probability using the generated copula:

```
pacman::p_load(copula, gamlss.dist)

# Generate Gumbel copula with theta=2
thetaVal <- 2
copula <- gumbelCopula(thetaVal, dim = 3)

copPre <- mvdc(copula, c("SHASH", "norm", "norm"),
               list(
                 list(mu = 46, sigma = 5, nu = 2, tau = 1),  # X SHASH
                 list(mean = 46, sd = 1),                      # Y normal
                 list(mean = 23, sd = 1)))                     # Z normal

pMvdc(c(47, 45, 22), copPre)
```

The last line of code gives the probability that `(X ≤ 47),(Y ≤ 45), and (Z ≤ 22)`.
I would like guidance on calculating the conditional distributions `F(Y|X)` and `F(X|Y)` using the provided values for `X`, `Z`, and `Y` and the copula model.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Do you want `F(Y | X=x)` or `F(X | X <= 47)`?

Comment: yes, both ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a conditional probability like `Pr(X <= x | Y <= y)`, you can use the formula `Pr(X <= x, Y <= y) / Pr(Y <= y)`:

```r
library(copula)
library(gamlss.dist)

# Generate Gumbel copula with theta=2
thetaVal <- 2
copula <- gumbelCopula(thetaVal, dim = 3)

copPre <- mvdc(copula, c("SHASH", "norm", "norm"),
               list(
                 list(mu = 46, sigma = 5, nu = 2, tau = 1),  # X SHASH
                 list(mean = 46, sd = 1),                      # Y normal
                 list(mean = 23, sd = 1)))                     # Z normal

pMvdc(c(47, 45, 22), copPre)

# Pr(X <= x | Y <= 45)
x <- 50
pMvdc(c(x, 45, Inf), copPre) / pnorm(45, 46, 1)
# or:
pMvdc(c(x, 45, Inf), copPre) / pMvdc(c(Inf, 45, Inf), copPre)
```

For `Pr(X <= x | Y = y)` you have to use the `cCopula` function, which is, to me, a bit complicated to understand.

```r
# Pr(X <= x | Y = y)
x <- 50
y <- 47
cCopula(
  cbind(pnorm(y, 46, 1), pSHASH(x, 46, 5, 2, 1)), 
  indices = 2, 
  copula = copula
)
```

[Some info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90283/how-to-find-conditional-probability-pxxy-y-using-copulas).

Comment: thank you very much!!!!!!! Could you please tell me what is happening when using `Inf` in `pMvdc`?

Comment: @user17326436 `Pr(X <= x, Y <= y, Z <= Inf) = Pr(X <= x, Y <= y)` because `Z <= Inf` is always true.